# ActionBar navigation tab item that starts an activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have an activity that uses ActionBarSherlock to show an action bar with navigation tabs. I need one of those tabs to open another activity (taking over the whole screen) when it is tapped. I built a custom TabListener to achieve this, but it fires when the tab contents are initially rendered, not just when it's manually selected.

I can't see a way to catch a traditional onClick event, so I assume I need to handle this in the TabListener and somehow distinguish the initial selection from a later manual selection, but how? I could use a counter each time the tab is selected and only start the secondary activity if the counter is above zero, but that looks like an ugly hack. I was hoping there was a way to handle a "click" as opposed to a "selection" as the latter includes both the initial display of the views, as well as later manual clicks.

I attach the listener to the action bar navigation tab like this:

```
tab.setTabListener(new TabDiseaseSelectorListener(this));
```

And then the listener looks like this:

```
    public class TabDiseaseSelectorListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private final Activity mActivity;

    public TabDiseaseSelectorListener(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction unused) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setClass(mActivity, DiseaseSelector.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction unused) {
    }

    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}
```

I tried using onTabReselected() but that only fires if the tab is already selected and the user taps it again.

Comment: "I need one of those tabs to open another activity (taking over the whole screen) when it is tapped." -- that's simply ghastly. It should not be a tab. Make it a toolbar button in the action bar, or an options menu item, or put a button in your main UI to launch this activity. Do not create a tab that, when tapped, replaces the whole UI. That would be akin to tapping a tab in Excel and having a copy of Internet Explorer launch while minimizing the Excel window entirely.

Comment: Yes, agree 100% it's awful, but in this case the client has mandated this and they pay the bill. I choose my fights carefully, and this one isn't worth fighting.